# webpack setup for react and express

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and webpacks. I am trying to get express and react to work by using webpacks but i get the following Err:**no configuration file found and no output filename configured via cli option. a configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory. use --help to display the cli options.**

This is my github file. Can anyone help me fix this?

https://github.com/moiscmigu/webpacks

Comment: you named your webpack config file wrong "webpack.congif.js"

Comment: what should i name it?

Comment: oops, damn i hate making those mistakes.

Comment: well man, just name it 'webpack.config.js' as the error suggests